# Is it possible to only change the font size of the current window?

Tags: vimscript

As title. Say I have two vertical splits, and I only want to increase the font size of the right split. Is this possible? If so:

1. What's the API to get the current font size?
2. What's the API to set the current font size?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I have two vertical splits, and I only want to increase the font size of the right split. Is this possible?

Unfortunately no, this is impossible. Vim is at heart a terminal based application where historically only a single font (plus fallbacks and bold and italics) could be used. GUI vim uses the same approach -- it only supports a 'single' font.

The "API" is only available for GUI vim with an option `guifont` you can set and get.

It is not ideal, but one can use it to create mappings to increase/decrease font size for the whole GVim (not per split window):

- https://github.com/habamax/.vim/blob/master/pack/local/start/vim-guifont-size/plugin/guifont_size.vim#L11-L11
- https://github.com/habamax/.vim/blob/master/pack/local/start/vim-guifont-size/autoload/guifont_size.vim#L16